# Keeping track of ticks across multiple threads

Tags: python

I'm trying my hand at simple animations and im using get_ticks() with booleans to determine when the animations begin and end:

```
if ticks >= 1000:
    alpha1 += alphaChange
    htpCap1.set_alpha(alpha1)
    windowSurface.blit(htpCap1, (0,110))

if ticks < 5000:
    windowSurface.blit(sprite, (spriteX,310))
    windowSurface.blit(wasd, (wasdX,600))
```

Problem is, ticks don't seem to reset after having first executed other modules. I'm guessing it keeps track of ticks across all modules, which means that the code above only works if I run it's module first.

So my question: is there a way to keep track of total ticks for each individual module? That way I could simply subtract the ticks from modules i previously ran.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are going to have to provide more context for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about which module you are using to 'get_ticks()', but if you can use the time module and call

```
time.clock()
```

to get the number of milliseconds since the process started. If you are interested in the number of ticks since the specific module was loaded, then you can simply store this value at the bottom of your module and do your compares relative to that value, so something like this (although I'm speculating because I don't know how you are calling the code you provided):

```
import time

def animate()
  if time.clock() - module_loaded_at >= 1000:
    alpha1 += alphaChange
    htpCap1.set_alpha(alpha1)
    windowSurface.blit(htpCap1, (0,110))

  if time.clock() - module_loaded_at < 5000:
    windowSurface.blit(sprite, (spriteX,310))
    windowSurface.blit(wasd, (wasdX,600))

module_loaded_at = time.clock()
while True:
   animate()
   time.sleep(0.05)
```